# Laravel Blade Display Only if Not Logged In

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware

I 'm using Laravel's middleware, and I'm trying to have an empty div if the user is not authenticated. Otherwise, I am trying to have a div that allows the user to create an account. I have tried the following:

```php
@auth
    <div class="form-group col-md-6"></div>
@else
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <h6>Create Account</h6>
    </div>
@endauth
```

**Routes**

```php
Route::get('/checkout', 'CheckoutController@index')->name('checkout.index')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/guestCheckout', 'CheckoutController@index')->name('guestCheckout.index');
```

**CheckoutController.php**

```php
if (auth()->user() && request()->is('guestCheckout')) {
    return redirect()->route('checkout.index');
}
```

The above does not work, and I have tried deleting the history, clearing caches, etc. but to no avail. Suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Define "does not work". What does happen? Which of the two do you see?

Comment: The empty div, but the user is not logged in. I'm trying to put this on the checkout/guest checkout page and I think I might be because of how I have CheckoutController.php set up. I will add more info up top.

Answer (score 3):

> *trying to have an empty div if user is not authenticated...*

Your blade setup is really close. Try this!

```
@auth 
 <!-- the user is authenticated --> 
 <div class="form-group col-md-6>
 </div>

@endauth <!-- note the end auth --> 


@guest
 <!-- the user is NOT authenticated --> 
 <div class="form-group col-md-6>
    <h6>Create Account</h6>
 </div>
@endguest
```

You can read up more about this [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#if-statements)

As for your controller, try using:

```
if( Auth::check() ) 
{
    // The user is authenticated.. 

} else {
    // The user is NOT authenticated.. 
}
```

Comment: @MatthewSpire did you give this a shot?

Answer (score 0):

There's out of the box way to do this!

```
@guest
  <div class="form-group col-md-6>
  </div>
@else
  <div class="form-group col-md-6>
    <h6>Create Account</h6>
  </div>
@endguest
```

You don't need the middleware thingy if I were you.

Comment: I tried that, it does not work and the empty div is displayed in all cases.

Comment: What version of Laravel if I may ask?

Answer (score 0):

The current (Laravel 8) way to do this is by using the Auth helper directives.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#authentication-directives

```blade
@auth
This only shows for logged in users
@endauth

@guest
This only shows for guests
@endguest
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Do it like this

```
    <ul>        
      @guest
        @if (Route::has('login'))
          <li><a class="nav-link scrollto {{Request::url() === route('login') ? 'active' : ''}}" href="{{route('login')}}">Login</a></li>
        @endif
        @if (Route::has('register'))
          <li><a class="nav-link scrollto {{Request::url() === route('register') ? 'active' : ''}}" href="{{route('register')}}">Register</a></li>
        @endif
        @else
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#"><span>{{ Auth::user()->name }}</span> <i class="bi bi-chevron-down"></i></a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="{{ route('logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">{{ __('Logout') }}</a>
                <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" class="d-none">
                      @csrf
                </form>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
      @endguest
    </ul>
```